# Бот aiogram "Засыпает" (перестает обрабатывать обновления) через некоторое кол-во времени после запуска без ошибок в консоли

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Возникла проблема с ботом - я его запускаю и некоторое время он работает стабильно и без ошибок. Однако, через N-ное кол-во времени бот просто перестает отвечать на команды/callback. Судя по логу видно, что он просто перестает обрабатывать обновления! Что примечательно, время обработки последнего обновления несколько выше среднего (скриншот прикрепил)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я заключал start_polling в try

```py
    async def main():
        try:
            await dp.start_polling(bot, skip_updates=True)
        except Exception as e:
            await print(f'Fatal bot error: {e}')
    
    # Функция main() запускается только в случае если скрипт запущен с этого файла
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
            asyncio.run(main())
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('Exit')
```

Но это проблему не решило, а ошибок в консоли как не было, так и нет. Также я попробовал приписать none_stop=True, но ситуация ухудшилась - бот начал уходить в сон чуть ли не сразу.

Еще могу сразу уточнить, то что медик непричем. Его ресурсов точно хватает, я проверял

Пожалуйста, подскажите что делать.

Comment: Тут надо собрать много инфы. Время всегда разное? Зависит ли зависание от количества команд? Когда происходят зависания - после команд или просто так в режиме простоя. Я бы обложил весь код логами и что бы бот каждую секунду в лог спамил "Я жив". Может у вас где бесконечный цикл затисался или ожидает данные от внешнего сервиса остановив весь процесс. Все возможно...